# Using a Returned Array in a Main Method

Tags: java, arrays, return

How do you use a array that has been returned, further on in a method?

I am trying to use an array created in `ArrayCreator.Create()` method (which returns the array) as the Array input for `ArrayCreator.Sort(*array here*)` method.

Is there a way of naming the returned array in the main method, and then just using it for `ArrayCreator.Sort(*array here*)` method?

I have tried using ArrayCreator.Sort(Create().Unsorted)

```
public void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan;
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayCreator.Create();

    System.out.println("Do you want to sort the Array (y/n)");
    char sort = scan.next().charAt(0);
    if (sort == 'y' || sort == 'Y') {
        ArrayCreator.Sort();
        System.out.println("Array has been sorted");
    }
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course the same as any other variable, like you already did with `scan` or `sort`:

```
Whatever[] array = ArrayCreator.create();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should start your methods with a lowercase. There are two ways you can do this. You can either:

Pass ArrayCreator.Create() as the parameter for ArrayCreator.Sort():

```
ArrayCreator.Sort(ArrayCreator.Create()); //the create method is called first since it returns the array used as the parameter
```

Or assign the return value from ArrayCreator.Create() as an array and pass it to ArrayCreator.Sort();

```
Object[] array = ArrayCreate.Create();
ArrayCreate.Sort(array);
```

**Note:** You'd want to take the second approach.

Comment: We don't know if `ArrayCreator.Sort(*array here*)` returns anything. If not (which is highly probable) using it as `ArrayCreator.Sort(ArrayCreator.Create());` is pointless because we will not be able to use this array anywhere.

Comment: @Pshemo What's that got to do with it? The question is asking how to pass an array obtained from ArrayCreator.Create() to ArrayCreator.Sort().

Comment: If `ArrayCreator.Sort` doesn't return reference to sorted array it will create same problem that OP has now. So it will not solve anything. Best way is to first create reference for array which we will get from `ArrayCreator.Create()` and use this reference in `ArrayCreate.Sort(array);` as you showed in second part of your answer. Also I don't criticize you but just trying to add more info to your answer. No hard feelings.